# Send SMS in java using site2SMS/way2sms

Tags: java, smslib

The following code is to send sms in JAVA language,

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class site2sms
{
    //Replace your site2sms username and password below
    static final String _userName = "username";
    static final String _password = "password";
    static final String _url = "http://smsapi.cikly.in/index.php";  
    //static final String _url = "http://smsapi.cikly.in/index.php";
    //static final String _url = "http://www.site2sms.com/user/send_sms_next.asp";
    static final String charset = "UTF-8";

    //to build the query string that will send a message
    private static String buildRequestString(String targetPhoneNo, String message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String [] params = new String [5];
        params[0] = _userName;
        params[1] = _password;
        params[2] = message;
        params[3] = targetPhoneNo;
        params[4] = "site2sms";

        String query = String.format("uid=%s&pwd=%s&msg=%s&phone=%s&provider=%s",
        URLEncoder.encode(params[0],charset),
        URLEncoder.encode(params[1],charset),
        URLEncoder.encode(params[2],charset),
        URLEncoder.encode(params[3],charset),
        URLEncoder.encode(params[4],charset)
        );
    return query;
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String reciever, String message) throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("hi!hello");
        //To establish the connection and perform the post request
        URLConnection connection = new URL(_url + "?" + buildRequestString(reciever,message)).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

        //This automatically fires the request and we can use it to determine the response status
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
        //System.out.println(br);

        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("enter Mobile No:");
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String testPhoneNo = scanIn.nextLine();
        scanIn.close();            
        String testMessage = "Sending Messages From java is not too hard";
        sendMessage(testPhoneNo,testMessage);
    }
}
```

when I run the program, there is **no compile error** and also **no runtime error**, but *message is not delivered to respective number.*

Pls help me, any suggestion can be accepted.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i need to send sms message using java through sms gateway like way2sms or site2sms

Comment: He asks: "What is the question?" You answer with :"I need to do x"
Thats neither an answer to his question, nor a question by itself. Please edit your question so it is one

Comment: ok, I am not able to deliver sms from above program.So I just want to know is there any error in the program, or for the alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is written in comments in your class : Replace your site2sms username and password. I guess you have to subsrcibe for an account in smsapi.cikly.in